# Arrange Image buttons side by side

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have 6 Image buttons or maybe 9 in future and I want to arrange 2 Image buttons side by side on every row

how can I do it?

I have used gridview but It wasnt what i wanted
here is my code

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            >


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/apple"
                android:id="@+id/apple"
                android:background="@null"
                 />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/googleplay"
                android:id="@+id/googlep"
                android:background="@null"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/psn"
                android:id="@+id/psn"
                android:background="@null"

                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/steam"
                android:id="@+id/steam"
                android:background="@null"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/xbox"
                android:id="@+id/xbox"
                android:background="@null"
                />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/amazon"
                android:background="@null"
                android:id="@+id/amazon"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: What was the problem with gridview?

Comment: Can you please post your existing code, issue with that and the expected behaviour?

Comment: @findusl it has a lot of codes to write  and i know there is more simple ways to do what i want and it arranges according phone size

Comment: @PrerakSola it does'nt have any special code imagine when user opens your app  wanna see 6 image buttons on your first page with customize arranging

Comment: I can imagine that. But what I cannot imagine is what issue you have unless you give the specifics.

Comment: @user3779449 You know that you can set the amount of columns a gridview should show? Then it will not change arrangement when phone get's bigger. It also shouldn't be so much code. The most in the adapter where you actually generate the image buttons. But even that should be not so big.

Comment: With only 6 or 9 buttons you can probably even forget about recycling elements in the adapter. Pretty sure it can handle that.

Comment: and how can I resize them?my Image buttons have large size@PrerakSola@findusl

Answer (score 0):

Create a vertical  recycler view and keep two buttons in  xml which you will inflate in it as you shown in figure and keep length to 3 in getItem count so you will get two button in every row  and six buttons in three row

Comment: would u please show a me an example i didn't get your meaning about getitem count @janardhan

Comment: getItemCount is a method in recycler view adapter which returns int i.e it basically tells how many rows we have for recycler view.for getItemCount=3 we have 3 rows

Comment: @user3779449 did you get it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3739976/janardhan-r
Unfortunately no and Im still searching for its solution  I created vertical view and kept two buttons in xml but they disappears and I searched about getitemcout what is its code?

Comment: They disappear means are they visible for some time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3739976/janardhan-r
Imagine I dragged RecyclerView from palette to component tree then I dragged 2 Image buttons inside of RecyclerView when I do it Image buttons will disappear on Preview